# Passing the current Angular.JS iterator into a function on form submit?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having trouble with the following HTML, and unfortunately I do not know the correct Angular.js terminology to title this question correctly.

```
<body ng-controller ="GuessingGamesController as gamesCtrl">
    <h1>Guessing Game Test Page</h1>
    <div id="Game">
        <h2>Test Game</h2>
        <form name="StartGameForm" ng-submit="gamesCtrl.startNewGame()" ng-show="{{gamesCtrl.game.id === -1}}">
            <input type="submit" value="Start New Game" />
        </form>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="turn in gamesCtrl.game.turns">
                {{turn.question}}?
                <form name="ReplyForm" ng-submit="gamesCtrl.nextTurn({{turn}})" novalidate>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="turn.answer" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The statement that fails is `ng-submit="gamesCtrl.nextTurn({{turn}})"` and the error I see in Chrome's developer console is

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column
>   21 of the expression [gamesCtrl.nextTurn({{turn}})] starting at
>   [{turn}})].

How should I pass the current Angular.JS iterator into a function on form submit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use interpolation inside an expression, just do:-

```
gamesCtrl.nextTurn(turn);
```

`turn` from the current executing scope will be passed in to the method `nextTurn`

You do not need to do interpolation in ng-show as well, you would just provide the expression that will be evaluated by the ng-show directive (and not the interpolated value, if you provide the interpolated value actual bound expression will become the value false/true that needs to be evaluated against the scope) :-

```
ng-show="gamesCtrl.game.id === -1"
```

Comment: Thanks - that's fixed things. Any chance you can expand on "actual bound expression will become the value false/true that needs to be evaluated against the scope", I'm a little confused by that.

Comment: @PSL Your answer works for me as well. However, why is it that every time a scoped variable appears elsewhere in the template, it is referred to in `{{}}` but when inside of the function, it is not? Your answer does a good job explaining what to switch but does not say why to switch it.

Comment: @Startec it is in [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) scroll down to argument section. When you need to specify _expression_ you need to specify expression and ***not*** the value of the expression, `{{expression}} => value`. Take a look **[at this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290581/angularjs-ng-show-doesnt-update-class-when-interval-triggers/28290614#28290614)** which goes a bit deeper. Does this clarify?

Comment: @dumbledad Sorry i think i never noticed your comment in this answer, however if you are still confused please see this [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290581/angularjs-ng-show-doesnt-update-class-when-interval-triggers/28290614#28290614), it has explanation.